# How to compute the following limit: $L= \lim\limits_{ x\to + \infty} \left[ (x+4)^{1+\frac{1}{x}} - x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}} \right]$

Tags: limits, analysis

I‘m wondering how to compute the following limit： $$\begin{align*}
L= \lim\limits_{ x\to + \infty} \left[ (x+4)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}  - x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}} \right] 
\end{align*}$$
I know that if a limit$\lim\limits_{x\to + \infty} f(x)-g(x)=A$ exists, then $x\to +\infty \implies f(x) \sim g(x)$ .

Here I suppose $(x+4)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}=f(x),x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}}=g(x)$ , we  have $$\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x\to + \infty} \exp\left( \ln \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right) &=\exp\left(\frac{ x\ln\left( 1+\frac{4}{x} \right)+\cos x \ln (x+4)}{x(x+\cos x)} \right) \\ &= \exp\left( \frac{\frac{\ln\left( 1+\frac{4}{x} \right)}{x}+ \frac{\cos x \ln(x+4)}{x^{2}}}{\left( 1+\frac{\cos x}{x} \right)} \right) \\ &= \exp(0)=1
\end{align*}$$
Thus I can't say $L$ doesn't exist. That is,  $L$ can exist, and it can also not exist.

Then I know that if $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=1$ ,and $f(x)$ is differentiable, then $x\to +\infty \implies f(x)-1 \sim \ln(f(x))$ so I change the original limit to be $$\begin{align*}
L=\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos s}} \left( \frac{(x+4)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}}}-1 \right) \sim \lim\limits_{ x\to + \infty} \left( x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}} \right) \ln\left( \cfrac{(x+4)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}}} \right)
\end{align*}$$
Then I got stuck here. Any help with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As $x\to+\infty,$
$$f(x)=x^{1+\frac1x}e^{\left(1+\frac1x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac4x\right)}=x^{1+\frac1x}e^{\frac4x+o\left(\frac1x\right)}=x^{1+\frac1x}\left(1+\frac4x+o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)$$
and
$$g(x)=x^{1+\frac1x}e^{\frac{\ln x}x\left(\frac1{1+\frac{\cos x}x}-1\right)}=x^{1+\frac1x}e^{o\left(\frac1x\right)}=x^{1+\frac1x}\left(1+o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)$$
hence
$$f(x)-g(x)\sim4x^{\frac1x}\to4.$$

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach is to trust the usual laws of algebra of limits and use them with a combination of standard limits.

Let us divide and multiply the given expression by $x$ to get $$x\left[\left(\frac{x+4}{x}\right)^{1+1/x}x^{1/x}-x^{1/(x+\cos x)} \right] $$ This is of the form $x(A-B) $ where both $A, B$ tend to $1$. And therefore the limit of the expression is same as that of $$x(\log A-\log B) $$ The above expression is $$x\left[\frac{\log x} {x} +\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)(\log (x+4)-\log x) - \frac{\log x} {x+\cos x} \right] $$ or $$\cos x\cdot\frac{\log x}{x+\cos x}+4\cdot\frac{x+1}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{4}\log\left(1+\frac{4}{x}\right) $$ The first term tends to $0$ and second term tends to $4$ so that the desired limit is $4$.

In the last step we used the following standard limits $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log x} {x} =0,\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log (1+t)}{t}=1$$ The reduction from $x(A-B) $ to $x(\log A-\log B) $ is based on the limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1$$ (prove this).

Answer (score 0):

(A) Calculus Way :

Take $y=1/x$.

$L = \lim\limits_{ x\to + \infty} \left[ (x+4)^{1+\frac{1}{x}} - x^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}} \right] = \lim\limits_{ y \to 0} \left[ (1+4y)^{1+y}/(y)^{1+y} - 1/(y)^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}} \right]$

$L = \lim\limits_{ y \to 0} \left[ \frac { (1+4y)^{1+y}(y)^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}} - (y)^{1+y} } { (y)^{1+y}y^{1+\frac{1}{x+\cos x}} } \right]$

This is $0/0$ , hence use LH rule to Differentiate the terms & get the Answer. Numerator will give $4$ when Differentiating $4y$ , which will be missing from Denominator. Hence Answer "should" be $4$.

It looks very cumbersome to use LH rule. Though it "should" give the Answer $4$ , it will take time & effort to make the necessary Calculations. I will give the alternate Intuitive Way which "should" give Equivalent Answer.

(B) Intuitive Way :

When $x \rightarrow \infty$ , $x+\cos(x) \approx x$ , hence $1+1/(x+\cos(x)) \approx 1+1/x \approx 1$

Both Exponents are $1$ , hence $L=(x+4)^1-(x)^1=4$
No other value will be Consistent.

(C) Puisuex Series :

It seems that the Series Expansion (where we are allowing terms with $1/x$ & other Negative Powers) is given by the Puisuex Series :
$4+\frac{4\log(x)+1}{x}+O((\frac{1}{x})^2)$
[[ according to wolfram ]]

Substituting $y=1/x$ & Plugging in $y=0$ , we will get $L=4$

Comment: The method in (B) smells of $f \sim g \implies f-g\to 0$ which is well-known to be false.  In particular, the method cannot show "if the limit exists, it is $4$" which is how I interpret the claim "no other value will be consistent."

Comment: [1] I verified that the Answer is $4$ via wolfram & other tools , @BrianMoehring , thus my usage of quotes for all instances of "should" , & then the cumbersome calculations were left over to OP , once it was made $0/0$ format. [2] I am not claiming (B) is rigorous , hence the Descriptive Title "Intuitive Way" !!

Comment: @BrianMoehring I find your comment very interesting, especially as I am generally ignorant in this area.  If it isn't too much trouble, could you provide a *similar* counter example, where intuition would suggest that the limit is some value $~A,~$ and where the limit does exist, but actually equals some value $~B \neq A~?$

Comment: @Prem Note I said neither that the limiting value of $4$ is incorrect nor that there was an issue of rigor.  The issue is that the method _you seem to be implying in (B)_ is itself invalid and a common error among students.  There is a value to non-rigorous "intuitive" solutions, but we need to draw the line when the most likely _intuition_ you might be imparting is incorrect.

Comment: @user2661923 The simplest example I can think of is that for any real $c$, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x^{1+c/(x\ln x)} - x^1\right)=c$$